# How to create object initializer once inside a function?

Tags: python

My code looks like this:

```
import English

# This is a global variable
language = English()
```

Now I need to define functions and one is below:

```
def relation(text):
    from extractors.extractor import Extractor
    en_extractor = Extractor(language)
    language.add_pipe(en_extractor)

    # The above 3 lines needs to be initialized only once for each call
    doc = language(text)
```

I don't want to initialize the Extractor before users' call the function 'relation' and want it to be initialized once only. How to achieve that effect?

Comment: why not just have those three lines outside the function call right below `language = English()`

Comment: This file holds APIs and not all users want to use the function 'relation'. Only when users call 'relation', then they are initialized.

Comment: I'm unclear where you're having trouble.  The code you posted delays those operations until `relation` is called, just as you ask -- as far as I can see.

Comment: But every time the 'relation' is called, the "en_extractor" has to be reinitialized. Right? I want to initialize it once only

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't recommend this, one way to achieve what you want is to use `global` variable:

```
en_extractor = None
def relation(text):
    from extractors.extractor import Extractor
    global en_extractor
    if not en_extractor:
        en_extractor = Extractor(language)
    language.add_pipe(en_extractor)

    # The above 3 lines needs to be initialized only once for each call
    doc = language(text)
```

`en_extractor` won't be initialized until the first function call, and it won't be re-initialized on the following function calls.

Comment: Why don't you suggest this? What's the usual way to do this? It should be very common.